# Bullets are missing when exporting PDF from Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, export, formatting

When I export a file to PDF from Google Documents, the bullets are missing. Is this a bug?

Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: I have been trying to duplicate this, but cannot. Bullets appear fine in any Google Doc I export to PDF. Maybe you could provide more information, such as the type of bullet you are using, how you applied that formatting, whether or not this is an imported document, etc.

Comment: I am refering to this document https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NdFj2sgwXQ0aMgtyXDNrzIIgyznhVjyYPfJVJP3mmF0/edit?hl=en. I'll try it on a blank doc tmr

Comment: Wow. Very odd. I am able to duplicate your problem. The PDF doesn't contain the bullets. However, if I export it to MS Word, it does have the bullets. I wonder if there is some kind of bug in Google's PDF conversion. I'll try a few more things...

Comment: Can you try this: 1. FILE - DOWNLOAD AS - WORD  2. upload that Word document  3. set the table border color to white to remove the strange table format.   This seemed to work for me. Now I'm able to download this as PDF and have it include the bullets.

Comment: here's the link to the *uploaded* Word doc that I had exported from your original. try exporting this to PDF now: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q6jo_GGvjs6Dwv66zR9imLx-ZdIALmA3mVcj0k6cyGM/edit?hl=en&authkey=CND84eAI

Answer (score 2):

Some one can prefer to just change the font of the list to Arial. 
I tried ubuntu, Droids and a couple of others, it is look like only Arial display bullets correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I found a true workaround. In my case, I was using non-standard bullets (a money symbol) and the bullets rendered as blank squares in the PDF view when going the usual *File → Download As → PDF* route.

The workaround: go to *File → Print → Open PDF in Preview*. It should render correctly. Then, simply save to your desktop or wherever.

<sub>* This is true for Mac. I am unsure whether this works on other platforms.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. This works for windows too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still experiencing any such problems exporting google docs, a work around would be to export to Word and then convert your word to a pdf.

---

For Mac users:

1. Open the word document and make necessary changes
2. Go to File -> Print
3. Select "Save as PDF"

   1. Either select "Destination" and "Save as PDF"
   2. Or if "Save as PDF" is not a Destination option, look for the "Save as PDF" button in the lower corner of the screen

---

For Windows Users:

1. Download Cute PDF Writer: http://www.cutepdf.com/products/CutePDF/writer.asp
2. Install the exe
3. Open the word document and make necessary changes
4. Go to File -> Print
5. Select Cute PDF as your printer and hit OK
6. Select the destination to save the file

Answer (score 0):

I also got into this problem and I've found a workaround as :

- Open the master slide and click on bullet on respective layout slide (View > Master)
- Again choose the same bullet from box

Download document, bullets appeared for me.